# Always getting ON_FOOT from Google Awareness API Detection Activity. How to get sub-activity WALKING?

Tags: android, google-api, google-awareness

I am using the class [DetectedActivity](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity) from the [Google Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/). When I walk or run, I always get the response `ON_FOOT`.

For example, when I am just walking, I want to get back [WALKING](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#WALKING) only but I still get [ON_FOOT](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#ON_FOOT). I do see the following note in the documentation but it doesn't tell how to get the ON_WALKING sub-activity information too?

> The device is on a user who is walking. This is a sub-activity of [ON_FOOT](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html#ON_FOOT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [getProbableActivities](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionResult.html#getProbableActivities()) to get the full list of probable activities: while `ON_FOOT` will be the most probable activity, looking at the second most probably activity will return `WALKING`, `RUNNING`, etc.